API post request working in PostMan, but not in Laravel Application
I am attempting to submit a list of domain aliases to an API endpoint, and as the title says, it works perfectly in PostMan.. but when I try to add it to my Laravel application, I am getting a "502 Bad Gateway" error.
The API in question is for Cloudways. Documentation can be found here: https://developers.cloudways.com/docs/#!/AppManagementApi#updateAppAliases
The specific endpoint in question is https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1/app/manage/aliases
In PostMan, I first hit https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1/oauth/access_token in order to get an access token. This runs fine, and it spits out a bearer token, as expected.
From there, I send that data along as a bearer token, along with the requested parameters.
I am sending the data as raw JSON, and it looks like so:
{
    "server_id": 111111,
    "app_id": 2222222,
    "aliases": ["testing.somedomain.com", "another.somedomain.com"]
}

When I submit this in PostMan, I get a 200 status, and I can check the application and see the domain aliases added, as expected.
From there, I take the code that PostMan produces, and paste it into a method in my Controller.
This is the code:
public function updateDomainAliases() {
    $domainList = array();
    foreach($allDomains as $key => $singleDomain) {
        $domain = $singleDomain->subdomain.".".$singleDomain->domain;
        $domainList[] = $domain;
    }

    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken(env('CLOUDWAYS_EMAIL'), env('CLOUDWAYS_API_KEY'));
    $domainResponse = $this->addDomainAliases($accessToken, env('CLOUDWAYS_SERVER_ID'), env('CLOUDWAYS_APP_ID'), $domainList);
}

private function getAccessToken($email, $apiKey) {
    $response = Http::post('https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1/oauth/access_token', [
        'email' => $email,
        'api_key' => $apiKey,
    ]);

    return $response->json()['access_token'];
}

private function addDomainAliases($accessToken, $serverID, $appID, $aliases) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1/app/manage/aliases',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
            "server_id": 111111,
            "app_id": 2222222,
            "aliases": ["testing.somedomain.com", "another.subdomain.com"]
        }',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}

So... as you can see, my first step is generating an Access Token, which a simple dd() command verifies is working properly.
I then send that access token to my addDomainAliases() function, along with the server ID, app ID, and aliases, and then run a cURL command to send the data to the API.
A couple of things worth noting here:

I had originally set the server ID, app ID, and aliases up as variables that I was passing in... but, when that wasn't working, I was just trying to get some hardcoded values functioning. I was suspicious that there was some kind of error in my single vs double quotes, or with string concatenation. So, I thought just using hardcoded values would fix the problem, and I could debug from there. Unfortunately... this did not fix the problem.

I have also tried using hardcoded access tokens, to no avail.

I have also tried other methods, such as sending the data via Guzzle, but still get the same error.

I did reach out to Cloudways support to see if there was an issue with this particular endpoint... but they seem to think it's something with the code.


So – I turn to you fine people. What am I missing here?

Edit:
Here are my Postman Requests:
Getting the Access Token:


Sending Domain Alias Data:




Edits: Part 2
I adjusted my addDomainAliases function as follows:
private function addDomainAliases($accessToken, $dump = null) {
    $url = 'https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1/app/manage/aliases';

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' .$accessToken
    ];

    $payload = [
        'server_id' => 111111,
        'app_id' => 2222222,
        'aliases' => ['testing.somedomain.com', 'another.somedomain.com']
    ];

    $request = Http::withOptions([
        'verify' => config('app.env') == 'production',
    ])->withHeaders($headers);

    if($dump) {
        $request->dd()->post($url, $payload);
    } else {
        $response = $request->post($url, $payload);
    }

    dd($response);

I then called the function first as so:
$addDomains = $this->addDomainAliases($accessToken, true);

Which gave me the following response:

I then called the same function, setting the second parameter to false.
In doing so, I once again got the 502 Bad Gateway error.

on your updateDomainAliases method, you have a variable $domainList, where is that define? did you also check the error log and see whats in there. lastly, post your postman request data and headers

@silver - I went in and added screenshots of my postman request data, as well as updated the code to show how I generating the $domainList. In this case, I'm not actually using the $domainList variable, as I attempted to just hardcode the data to get THAT working, before I started trying to get dynamically generated data working. However... for the sake of leaving no stone unturned, I added it back in.

1st, check the laravel error log in /storage/logs and see whats in there when you try to do a request.
2nd, dont use env function, use config instead, the env function should only be use in configuration files, once the configuration is cache, that function will return null, any call outside config files should use config function. you can add another file inside /config for your API keys that calls the env function, or just add it in /config/app.php file
3rd, use the HTTP Client instead of using curl, this way, you can easily debug and verify your actual request.
below is a sample of your addDomainAliases method that uses HTTP client. if you pass true in 2nd param, you will see the actual request headers, body and all request related data
private function addDomainAliases($accessToken, $dump = null ) {

    $url = 'https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1/app/manage/aliases';

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken
    ];
    
    $payload = [
        'server_id' => '111111'
        'app_id' => '2222222'
        'aliases' => ['testing.somedomain.com', 'another.subdomain.com']
    ];

    $request = Http::withOptions([
        'verify' => config('app.env') == 'production',
    ])->withHeaders($headers);

    // dump the actual request and verify the url, headers and payload are all correct
    if ( $dump ) 
        $request->dd()->post($url, $payload );

    $response = $request->post( $url, $payload );

    .
    .
    .
        
}

Additionally, also very that your getAccessToken request also returns the data you expect, if not also dump its request and verify all data are correct

Edited my post, with some extra context/responses based on this answer.

you still haven't provided what's written in error log

Also check your server log whats in there.
